# How to change the list structure indentation?

Tags: lists, indentation, enumerate, itemize, description

In the example below, the item "Long item text" will be wrapped to the next line if it exceeds the width. But this continued second line is further indented to the same extent as "Item description" is. Can you think of a way to give the continued "item text" have the same indentation as it's first line? Thank you for your time.

```
\begin{description}
  \item[*] Long item text \hfill \\
    Item description
\end{description}
```

I'd like to have it so:

```
* Long item text ...
  that continues here.
    Item description
```

Comment: please make a _complete_ small example document that shows this effect, don't just post fragments of code.

Answer (score 5):

It's not quite clear which layout ypu want but `enumitem` package makes it easy to experiment with the parameters. perhaps:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{description}[itemindent=0pt,listparindent=2em,labelwidth=1em,]
  \item[*] Long item text 
 that continues here.
 that continues here.
 that continues here.
 that continues here.
 that continues here.

    Item description
that continues here.
that continues here.
that continues here.
that continues here.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Very similar to David's solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[itemindent=!,labelwidth=!,listparindent=\parindent]
  \item[*] Long item text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

  Item description
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]